# CSS how to style HTML page like print preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My problem is that I want to style my CSS page to make it looks like in "print preview". I used `@media print` CSS to make rules for printing. But I don't know exactly how to design my HTML page, for example: I set `div` size as `A4` format, but if text inside this `div` is longer than A4 height how can I move some part of `div` to other "A4" `div`?

Comment: please show what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

> If text inside this div is longer than a4 height how can I move some part of div to other "a4" div?

*You need to use* `page-break` *in CSS to make the content come correctly against the pages. There are two properties, which help you achieve this:* `page-break-after`, `page-break-before`, `page-break-inside`. *You can refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after) for more information about that.*

> I don't know exactly how to design my HTML page.

*Make sure you don't use* `position`*, and* `float` *inside your pages. That's a good way. Keep only those that are required and use* `display: none` *to hide others.*